# Python Code Error random script

Tags: python

```
import random, string    
max_str_length = 20
while True:
    random = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for _ in range(random.choice(range(1, max_str_length))))
    print random
    if random=="hugh":
        print "Done"
```

What's the error here? It says "Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'"

Comment: rename that `random` variable: `random_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase)...)`

Comment: You're setting `random` equal to a string and then trying to call a method on it.

Comment: Done, but now it says "Unexpected Indent" for "print random_str"

Comment: You probably mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: How would I make a random amount of letters, capital? And how would I add numbers into it?

Answer (score 1):

You define `random` as a string on the first line of your while loop, and then try to call a method on it that doesn't belong to `str`. Changing the name will fix your problem.